# Wordpress: Create blog posts from Tweets and YouTube videos automatically?

Tags: wordpress, post, twitter, youtube

I am building a Wordpress site, but I'm struggling to find a good plugin to achieve a few things...

Basically I want to make the website a central hub of a lot of my social networks, without me having to continaully update things in several places. So I'm wanting to do the following:

Every time I post a new Tweet, I want it to create a new Blog post on my website in the Tweet category. The post should have a default featured image and a I should also be able to set where the Tweet is displayed (i.e. in the title and post content) and if anything else is displayed after the tweet (like a follow button) for example.

Secondly, every time I upload a new video to YouTube, I want it to create a new blog post on my site in the Video category (and preferably in the Video Post Type) automatically. Again, I should have control over what is pulled into the post other than the video... for example description, tags etc. I would also like it to set the Featured Image of the post to one of the three still images that YouTube creates for a video.

Is the above achievable, and how would I go about figuring it out?

Many thanks in advance,

HT

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, I'm doing something similar. I'm using Twitter Tools plugin; along with Social.

HTH